# need to have certain Output

Tags: python

translation:

2 Write the function rowZero (length) - it will print a line with a given length of only zeros. Write the

function rowZeroOne (length, position) - it will print a line of zeros with one at the selected position. Unit position <= row length

3 rowZeroSymbot (length, position, symbol) will print a line of zeros, place a symbol at the selected position

4 Create a matrixWrapper (function, size, symbol) function that prints:

a. identity matrix

b. matrix of zeros with any symbol on the diagonal

matrixWrapper (rowZero, 5)
or
matrixWrapper (rowZeroOne, 5)

result:

Be aware of the default values of the function arguments

```
def rowZero(y, s):
   for x in range(y):
    print('0', end='')
    if y == s:
      print('1', end='')
      
    
rowZero(10, 10)
```

here is my solution, but it's wrong, cause it's adding `1` instead of replacing it

Answer (score -1):

Print `1` in the `if`, and `0` in the `else`.

```
def rotZeroOne(length, position):
    for x in range(length):
        if x == position:
            print('1', end='')
        else:
            print('0', end='')
    print()
```